# Restore column value after many updates

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to return the old value for the `discount_price` column after many updates on the table?

Here are some of my updates

```
UPDATE products SET discount_price = discount_price + 0.95
   WHERE discount_price >= 1  AND discount_price <= 10;

UPDATE products SET discount_price = discount_price + 1.5
   WHERE discount_price >= 10 AND discount_price <= 30;

UPDATE products SET discount_price = discount_price + 2
   WHERE discount_price >= 30 AND discount_price <= 50;

UPDATE products SET discount_price = discount_price + 3
   WHERE discount_price >= 50 AND discount_price <= 100;
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: How does it relate to phppgadmin? Is it PostgreSQL or MySQL? Please edit and explain more about what you want to do.

Comment: oh sorry, 

I am using postgresql

Comment: @jarlh

oh sorry, I am using postgresql

Comment: Which old value do you expect? For example discount_price 9.5 will be updated twice, first to 10.55, then to 11.95.

Comment: Consider having one single UPDATE, with a case expression to chose the update value.

Comment: @jarlh Yes this is my fault, I am asking if there any update statement to return discount_price column to old value if its possible

Comment: You say return, does that mean you want to know the original value, but still store the new value? Or do you want to revert (rollback) the updates and store the original value?

Comment: @jarlh 
yes I need to rollback the updates 

In another meaning.  I've done many mistakes in my update statements is there any solution for this, to return the values to first value before any update statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you apply the changes inside a transaction, you can cancel the transaction with `ROLLBACK` to undo the changes.

There is no way to undo an `UPDATE` once the transaction is committed.

To get back data as they were in the past, you have to restore the database from a backup.

If you are a PostgreSQL expert and `VACUUM` has not yet run, you can use the [`pageinspect`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pageinspect.html) contrib module to get old data from a table.

Comment: Suppose I made 3 updates for the first update statement 
Example: 
UPDATE products SET discount_price = discount_price + 0.95
   WHERE discount_price >= 1  AND discount_price <= 10;

Then 

UPDATE products SET discount_price = discount_price - 0.95
   WHERE discount_price >= 1  AND discount_price <= 10;

then 
UPDATE products SET discount_price = discount_price - 0.95
   WHERE discount_price >= 1  AND discount_price <= 5.95;

I mean I've done many mistakes in my update statements
is there any solution for this, to return the values to first value before any update statements

Comment: @MohammadKanaan, kindly ask the DBA to restore the database from a backup.

Comment: I have extended the answer, but unless you are an expert or you have a backup, the old data are lost.